# Can I install cultured/stone veneer over exterior foundation wall?

Tags: foundation, exterior, stone, veneer, install

The exposed exterior foundation walls on my home are covered in foam insulation. While practical, it's not the best look, and is also slowly being damaged over time. There is about 2.5 feet from grade to where the siding starts.

I was thinking about installing stone veneer over, but I really can't find anything that shows how to do this, or if it's even possible over foam/concrete. All the references I find relate to foam/wood backing. Anyone have any experience with this that could point me in the right direction if it's even possible? Open to other suggestions as well!

Answer (score 2):

A stucco coating (fiber-reinforced usually) is pretty standard for protection of exterior foam above grade.

That can simply be applied to the foam.

Stone veneer (being considerably heavier than stucco, despite being described as "lightweight") would require a much more substantial support. A metal lath attached to the wall appears to be typical. There's an obvious need to use appropriate masonry anchors for the screws to support the lath, other than that, it should not differ greatly from applying it to a wood wall.